# How to print only MongoDB inserted item to the screen?

Tags: mongodb, collections

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
//Establishing the connection
var new_db = "mongodb://localhost:27017/demo_db"

//File Name is  : demo-db.js
//establishing the connection
mongo.connect(new_db ,(error , client) => {
if (error){
    throw error;
}
var db = client.db('mytestdb');
//console.log("Database demo_db created successfully");
//To close the connection
var data ={ name : "name" , age : "age" , nation : "VN" }

db.collection("details").insertOne(data,(err , coll) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(coll);

});

client.close();
});
```

**Problem**: When I print the collection with *console.log(coll)*, I expect name, nation, age only. However, I receive a long JSON object:

```
{CommandResult {
result: { n: 1, ok: 1 },
connection:
Connection {
domain: null,
_events:
{ error: [Function],
...
```

with the information I need (name, age,...) in the end.

How to print only inserted item to the screen, instead of long JSON object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simply what the callback function returns as a response from the database operation `insertOne`. You can access the inserted item by:

```
coll.ops[0]
```

This will be an object like:

```
{ 
  name: "name",
  age: "age",
  nation: "VN",
  _id: Buffer(12) // Buffer containing the ObjectID of the inserted item
}
```